# Casting nested ienumerable dynamic to custom classes

Tags: c#, linq, 2sxc

I have these classes:

```
public class mDiagnosis {
    public int xId {get;set;}
    public string xName {get;set;}
    public List<mICNconcepts> xFocus {get;set;}
}

public class mICNconcepts {
    public int xId {get;set;}
    public string xName {get;set;}
}
```

And this ienumerable dynamic: tDiagnosis, where one of it's field is another (Focus) is another ienumerable dynamic.

I'm trying to cast the dynamic entities to the custom classes, but the nested one errors at .Select(j => new mICNconcepts() {

```
var tDiagnosis = AsList(App.Data["Diagnosis"]);
var typed = AsList(tDiagnosis)
            .Select(i => new mDiagnosis() {
                xId = i.EntityId,
                xName = i.Whatever,
                xFocus = AsList(i.Focus)
                    .Select(j => new mICNconcepts() {
                        xId = 1,
                        xName = "asd"
                    })
            });

CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

The first ".Select(i => new mDiagnosis()" works fine. It's the second one that gives problems.

Perhaps a particular way 2sxc resolves these entities? They are both dynamic.

Please don't close just because the other topic mentions the same error. The issues don't seem to be related.

Comment: what is `AsList`?

Comment: Since `tDiagnosis` is `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, the compiler knows (more or less) what kind of delegate the `Select` method will take. But since `i` and `i.Focus` are `dynamic`, `AsList(i.Focus)` also returns a `dynamic`, not an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. You'll need to cast `i.Focus` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` so C# knows what the `.Select()` means in that context.

Comment: The duplicate actually is the same issue that you're running into: they have a `dynamic` that they're trying to treat as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, just like you do.

Comment: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<mICNconcepts>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<mICNconcepts>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: This is a weakness in the Razor compiler. `AsList(...)` returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which is known, BUT if the parameter in `AsList(somethingDynamic)` is dynamic, then the compiler declares that it can't be sure which `AsList(...)` was used (even if there is only one). Because there could be an `AsList(string)` and an `AsList(object)` - even though there isn't. So what Razor needs is that after the second AsList you tell it that it's as `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Then you're fine.

Comment: We usually first add this line `@using Dynlist = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>;` and then do `AsList(somethingdynamic) as Dynlist` - you can see an example here: https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/linq108/page